# JavaFX nodes size chaging after calling the same code

Tags: javafx

I started to encounter a problem with the size of nodes, be it `Button` or `Text`, where they change the size when calling the exact same block of code. In the UI I added an option for the user to change the colors, and after that is done, the function that adds the nodes is called again and is showing them with the new colors, that is how I saw the problem. In some situations the width is increased, in others the height is increased. It may not seem a lot, but when you have multiple nodes that are resized, it becomes a problem. Can anyone explain why this is happening and what to do to avoid it?

Here is a simple example, and in this case the width is increased, simply click on the pane to see the difference:

[image]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Cursor;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Background;
import javafx.scene.layout.BackgroundFill;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class TestingSize extends Application {
    static Stage stage;
    static Pane pane;
    static Scene scene;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        pane = new AnchorPane();
        scene = new Scene(pane);
        stage = primaryStage;
        stage.setScene(scene);

        show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    static void show() {
        pane.getChildren().clear();
        Background backgroundEnter = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.GREEN, null, null));
        Background backgroundExit = new Background(new BackgroundFill(Color.RED, null, null));
        Font font = new Font("Arial", 16);
        Text text = new Text("Test");
        text.setFont(font);
        Insets insets = new Insets(Math.ceil(text.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() * 0.3),
                Math.ceil(text.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() * 0.6),
                Math.ceil(text.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() * 0.3),
                Math.ceil(text.getLayoutBounds().getHeight() * 0.6));

        Button button = new Button("Test");
        button.setLayoutX(20);
        button.setLayoutY(20);
        button.setPadding(insets);
        button.setFont(font);
        button.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
        button.setBackground(backgroundExit);
        button.setOnMouseEntered(event -> {
            button.setTextFill(Color.YELLOW);
            button.setBackground(backgroundEnter);
            scene.setCursor(Cursor.HAND);
        });
        button.setOnMouseExited(event -> {
            button.setTextFill(Color.BLUE);
            button.setBackground(backgroundExit);
            scene.setCursor(Cursor.DEFAULT);
        });
        pane.getChildren().add(button);

        pane.setOnMouseClicked(event -> {
            show();
        });

        stage.setWidth(150);
        stage.setHeight(150);
        if (!stage.isShowing()) {
            stage.centerOnScreen();
            stage.show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: When posting code, please include imports so that it will be complete and compile and perform the appropriate indentation (see [edits](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69441030/revisions)).

Comment: This looks like something that can be easily fixed if you use the `Parent` nodes correctly. Currently, you have a node floating around in an `AnchorPane`, and it is not anchored in any kind of way. Take the time to do some tutorials and learn more about how to use the `Parent` nodes.

Comment: That is not a problem of anchoring the node, because it is not moving around the `Parent`, but it's size is changing, it becomes wider then in the first run.

Comment: `getLayoutBounds` mentions, "Because the computation of `layoutBounds` is often tied to a node's geometric variables, it is an error to bind any such variables to an expression that depends upon `layoutBounds`." What is the actual goal?

Comment: If you are talking about the formula I used for creating the `Insets` object, then I used that so I know what is the height and the width of a `Button` for example, by getting the height of the text inside it, and because I set a value that I know what it is for padding, I know the height of that `Button`, which you can't get by simply using `.getHeight()` because the values is not set until it is showed, which is too late if I want to have other nodes set to a position that depends on that `Button` position. Also I am giving the user the option to choose the font family and size.

Comment: But when it comes to a `Text` object, I found that you can know it's size before it is showed by using `.getLayoutBounds.getHeight()/.getWidth()`, and that is why I used that formula.

Comment: I don’t know why the height of the `Text` is reported differently on the first run of your method to subsequent runs. This code just feels like it is fighting against the API, though. If you want to position nodes relative to other nodes, the appropriate way to do that is with a layout pane. In the (unlikely) event that no predefined layout panes achieve what you want, you should subclass `Pane` and perform the layout in the `layoutChildren()` method. I’m not sure exactly how to create insets which are proportional to the size of the text, though.

Comment: I could use `H/VBox` or `GridPane` in some situations, but I have some that the nods are placed more randomly and I can't use them. But I found another way to calculate the width and height that doesn't depend on `layoutBounds` which does appear to be the problem with the use of `Text`. I'll do some more testing to see if it really works and I'll post the solution after.